# Saltstack - Preview Highstate

Tags: salt-stack

Is there a way to preview what files will be served to a minion on a `state.highstate`? I know that you can run `state.show_highstate`, but that is not the output I am looking for. For example, inside `/path/to/recurse/dir/` I have `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` and in my sls file I have

```
/path/to/recurse/dir/:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://dir/
```

I would like to run `state.preview_highstate` and it would show me the contents of `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`. Does anyone know how to go about this without just running `state.highstate`?

Comment: Since the states are executed on the minions I don't think there is a way to see the files before they are processed by the minion.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Even so, is it possible to determine the source of files? I know I've run into situations where it has been serving an "incorrect" file and I couldn't figure out where it was coming from. This was mostly when I switched to Github for the backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are able to run the state on the minion but just don't want to apply any changes you can append the `test=True` to your command:

```
salt '*' state.highstate test=True
```

This will run the highstate on the minion but will not make any changes to the system. Changes that would be applied are shown in yellow.

Comment: That's right, I had forgotten about that. Also, I tested and it works when run from the master as well.